# How to reallocate an unused partition on my HD?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, gparted

I had 2 partitions on my hard disk: one with Windows 10 and another one with Ubuntu 18.04. As I don't wanna the Windows anymore I've deleted the Windows partition and now I'm trying to add all its unallocated space to the Ubuntu partition.

I'm able to modify the unallocated partition, but I cannot resize with the Ubuntu. I've created a bootable USB pendrive with GParted Live and still not being able to do reallocate the space.

Does anyone know how to do it, please?

[I'm not able to add images here - you can see my partitions list on this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3qe9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend the "Extended" partition first, then you can extend the Logical partition inside it.

Your disk is laid out using an MBR partition style, which is limiting itself to 4 Primary partitions. To work around this, Ubuntu created an Extended partition for the last partition, then created the partitions for your file system inside of it.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by "you need to extend the Extended partition"? How I could extend it? I'm afraid to modify this partition as it contains the Ubuntu with the main/important files.

Comment: Expand `/dev/sda3` to cover all the Unallocated Space. Then, you can extend `/dev/sda5` to fill the remaining space.